# How do I restart the Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

My Nintendo Switch can't connect to the internet. Other devices are connected fine and the Switch is connected to my WiFi, however the Switch won't connect to the internet. Nintendo's network status page says all services are up.

I'd like to restart my Switch, but can't find anyway to do it.

**How do I restart my Switch?**

Comment: Turning it off and on doesn't restart it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Holding the power button (located on the top of the Switch) opens a menu that gives you the option to power the system off entirely.

To answer the problem, rather than the question though: I had a similar issue with my wi-fi not long ago.  Rather than powering the *system* off and on again, I found it was enough to cycle the *network adapter* by putting the system in Airplane mode and then taking it out, which is in the same home button menu as the sleep option.

Answer (score 6):

Use the power button on the top. The Home button is only used to put the Switch into sleep mode.